# Is there a way to create a tuple in Python with a lenght 'n' given by a list.?

Tags: python

In my case I have a list of assets and I want to create a tuple (0,1.0) for defining a constraint for each asset. If I have 3 assets i can just create the tuple by:

```
bounds = ((0,1.0),(0,1.0),(0,1.0))
```

How can I automate this process if for example I have 1000 assets?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create tuple with a loop in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48837384/how-to-create-tuple-with-a-loop-in-python)

Answer (score 1):

Use a generator expression.

```
bounds = tuple((0, 1.0) for _ in range(1000))
```

If you already have some other non-tuple iterable of constraints, just pass it to `tuple`:

```
bounds = tuple(the_constraints)
```

Answer (score 1):

since tuples are immutable you can just use multiplication to create 1000 identical tuples

```
bounds = ((0, 1.0),)*1000
```

(caution: do not do that with `list` type as it just duplicates the reference)

Answer (score 0):

If the list of assets is a list of lists then just map tuple to them:

```
tuple(map(tuple, asset_list))
```